# How to install u-torrent from a tar.gz on Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, bittorrent, tar

I am trying to install u-torrent, from utserver.tar.gz file. I have used the commands:

```
root@kali:~# cd ~/Desktop
root@kali:~/Desktop# ls
[kickass.so]easy.recovery.essentials.pro.win.8.7.xp.torrent  utserver.tar.gz
root@kali:~/Desktop# tar zxf utserver.tar.gz
root@kali:~/Desktop# ls
[kickass.so]easy.recovery.essentials.pro.win.8.7.xp.torrent  utserver.tar.gz
utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3
root@kali:~/Desktop# cd utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3
root@kali:~/Desktop/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3# ls
docs  utserver  webui.zip
root@kali:~/Desktop/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3# cat README|less
cat: README: No such file or directory
root@kali:~/Desktop/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3# xdg -open INSTALL
bash: xdg: command not found
```

I have extracted it, but in the extracted file I could not find ***install*** or ***readme***, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/104097) which might be helpful. However, I'm not currently on any of my computers running Linux so I cannot try it out for myself. Regardless, I would like to recommend [qbittorrent](http://qbittorrent.sourceforge.net/) *([install guide](http://kali4hackers.blogspot.se/2013/05/how-to-install-utorrent-in-kali-linux.html))* if you keep running into issues. All you need to do is add the debian source and do a simple:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install qbittorrent
```

I use it myself and am very fond of it.

Hope this helps!